# PHP and jQuery with MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update a database entry through jQuery and AJAX. I am checking that the values i send over is correct - but I am not sure how to check why the database is not updated.

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".approve", function(){
    var classes = $(this).parents('div:eq(0)'); // this gets the parent classes.
    i = 0;
    var pros = [];
    classes.find(".prosncons .pros ul li").each(function(){
        pros.push($(this).text());
    });
    var cons = [];
    classes.find(".prosncons .cons ul li").each(function(){
        cons.push($(this).text());
    });
    var notes = classes.find(".notes").text();
    var id = classes.find(".id").text();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../scripts/upload.php",
      data: { method: "approve", pros: pros, cons:cons, notes:notes, id:id },
      success: $(this).closest(".approval").remove()
    });
});
```

PHP::

```
    require("connection.php");

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $pros = $_POST['pros'];
    $cons = $_POST['cons'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $method = $_POST['method'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if($method == "approve"){
        $sql = "UPDATE `approval` SET approved = 1 WHERE pros=:pros AND cons=:cons AND notes=:notes AND id=:id";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array(':pros' => $pros, ':cons' => $cons, ':notes' => $notes, ':id'=> $id));
        echo $conn->error;
    }
    else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `approval` VALUES(null, :title, :pros, :cons, :notes, 0)";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':pros' => $pros, ':cons' => $cons, ':notes' => $notes));
    }
```

Comment: Echo the mysql errors out to the response. They will be in the data that is the first argument of your ajax callback. You can log that to the console and look at it.

Comment: Okay they are going through as just "array" - I need to change the arrays to actual text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not insert a array directly to mysql as mysql doesn't understand php data types.Mysql only understands SQL. So to insert this array into a mysql database you have to convert it to an sql statement.You canchange your **pros** and **cons** values to comma separated string or any any type of string.